# How to show pdf on the mobile browser?

Tags: pdf, mobile, browser, cross-browser, cross-platform

I am using iframe to embed a pdf on my web application , it is intended to support for all device , (desktop , mobile browsers) .

The problem is , on the desktop version it show perfectly (as chrome, fx has their own viewer).

However, when I view my website on ios/ android (android almost all browser not working) (ios Safari can show the pdf but without any function (e.g. zoom) ) .

How can I handle the mobile browsers (ios safari) (android chrome, fx and default one) if I need to display the pdf instead of download? thanks

```
<iframe src=”a.pdf” style=”width:600px; height:500px;” frameborder=”0″></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF's in `iframe`s are not cross-Browser consistent, and there is not a lot you can do about it. The user may have to scroll in some `iframe`s on certain Browsers. You may want to consider

```
<a href='a.pdf'>PDF Name</a>
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help . Then the user will click on the link to download the pdf file instead of viewing it on the browser?

Comment: Not necessarily. If the Browser has a feature or plug-in that shows the PDF it will display within a full Browser page, otherwise it will try to download, unless the proper headers are sent.

Comment: Since I have put a lightbox that surround the iframe , can I show it within the lightbox ? thanks

Comment: You won't see anything but the `PDF Name` in the code above, so there is no need to use a lightbox using the link. There is really no way to make sure a PDF will fit perfectly into lightbox or a new window no matter what you do. If the users window is too small, scroll bars may appear, depending on the Browser.